# changing of uiview orientation when a button clicked

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

how can i change the uiview interface orientation when i was clicked a button.

Comment: Do you mean you have a view you want to rotate, or you want to invoke the normal fullscreen rotation programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

`[application setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];` ?